# TCP Java server, Python client String not equal

Tags: java, python, string, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP connection between a Java server and Python Client.
when 'q' is sent from any to the other connection must be closed.
It works when I send 'q' from python to java. However, when I sent 'q' from java to python it does not work. I tried typecasting but no use.

Java Server:

public class Sender {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String fromclient;

    ServerSocket Server = new ServerSocket(25000);

    System.out.println("TCPServer Waiting for client on port 25000");

    while (true) {
        Socket connected = Server.accept();
        System.out.println(
                " THE CLIENT" + " " + connected.getInetAddress() + ":" + connected.getPort() + " IS CONNECTED ");

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connected.getOutputStream(), true);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        while (true) {
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            out.println(input);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Python Client:

```
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(("localhost", 25000))
while True:
    r, _, _ = select.select([client_socket], [], [])
    if r:
        data = client_socket.recv(4096)
        string_data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print str(string_data) == 'q'
        if str(string_data) == 'q' or string_data == 'Q':
            print ('Connection closed')
            client_socket.close()
            break
        else:
            print (string_data)
```

The statement print str(string_data) == 'q' always returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your Java server code from `out.println(input)` to `out.print(input)`. Add also an `out.flush()` to force that the data are send immediately not only after the buffer is filled.

`println` - would also send the linebreak to the client

With `print` it works as expected.

**edit** Some additonal. In such a case it helps on the Python client to print out the bytes in `data`.

Amend the Python client code as

```
data = client_socket.recv(4096)
for i in bytearray(data):
    sys.stdout.write(hex(i) + " ")
print
```

Assumed input on Java is `q+ENTER`. See below the output on the Pathon client side.

using on Java server side `out.println`

```
0x71 0xd 0xa
False
q
```

using on Java server side `out.print`

```
0x71
True
Connection closed
```

That way it's easy to spot the additional bytes (`0xd 0xa`) which were sent to the client.

Answer (score -1):

I think the encoding is the problem. Just comment out the encoding part and the code should work.

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: Findout the encoding of the java side using the Charset.defaultCharset() or system property or InputStreamReader.getEncoding and use the same on python side

Comment: the encoding is UTF-8

Comment: Then check the standard encoding alias please.